# Pressure Reducing Valve at water meter--need some assistance--how install, what parts, tools. Newbie

Tags: valve

How to put in PRV Valve 12 foot after home water meter. 
Thanks for your kind help. I may end up hiring a plumber but for $600 that 2 neighbors spent, I wonder if this is something I can do myself or someone with more skills than I.

This is what 2 neighbors had put in, looks like it is PVC:

[image: Picture of what neighbors put in]
Questions:

1. 3/4" Pipe is coming out of water meter. I cannot see if it is PEX or PVC. House was built in 2001, Thoughts????

.
2. If I use this type of PRV (below image) what parts/tools do I need to connect it?
[image]

3. If I use this type PRV (below image) what parts/tools would I need? Or would this not work the way the joints are?

[image: PRV Valve with Double Union]

I appreciate your knowledge and advice in advance

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 1):

The picture of your neighbors is a PEX pipe. The first PRV is national pipe thread. The Second one is  PEX and it's very easy to do this work. If you're using PEX then the second one is the obvious choice. You need a crimper and a pipe slicer. That's it. That being said, by the time you buy those tools and the PRV you could be pretty close to 600 bucks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly PEX. PVC would not be used on residential interior water supply lines in the US. Looks like a crimp or slip-on band connection of the PEX to the water meter.

The second picture looks like the correct fittings to accept PEX, but maybe not for your type of PEX. There are several types of PEX and each has a different type of connection. Unless you have time to research this and choose the right kind of fittings and can rent the specific installation tool for your PEX, I suggest you get it done by a competent professional that has done an acceptable job for a neighbor.

**EDIT** [Different types of PEX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sldHS1DPpLk). [More info](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8J1yHRuFWs). [Still more.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fT2ftQ_ab-w)

**EDIT** [PEX A vs PEX B](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRNKDrGlOls)

Comment: Thank you very much. The PSI is 135 psi. Thought a crimping tool (< $100) would do the trick as the PRV is less than $100. Prob get a plumber. Was trying to save a few hundred being retired but rather not chance things I guess.